# Twilio "Unable to create Room" error comes up in JS API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

For some reason I'm unable to create a room directly out of JS API like this:

```
TwillioVideo.connect(twillioToken, {name: 'my-name'})
  .then(room => {
    ....
  }, error => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to Room: ' + error.message);
  })
```

`.connect` method only works for me if the room was previously created, for instance:

I create the room first with C# like this:

```
public string CreateRoom(string roomName) {
 TwilioClient.Init(_twilioSettings.AccountSid, _twilioSettings.AuthToken);
 RoomResource room = RoomResource.Create(uniqueName: roomName);
 return room.Sid;
}
```

then after it is created i can connect to it no problem.
So I'm forced to create a room in C# api and then use it in JS API. But i would rather avoid this step.

Also I did not find a way to determine if the room with the unique name already exist prior to calling `RoomResource.Create(uniqueName: roomName)` because if it does exist this method throws an exception. But i would rather return an SID of existing room in that case

Please advise

Comment: Hey, have you followed the [steps to permit ad-hoc room creation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms#ad-hoc-rooms)?

Comment: @philnash I just looked at it and checked my settings, appears to be that "client-side room creation" was disabled for me. I will try enabling it(default appears to be enabled) and retest it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to create rooms via the JS SDK, you need to have to have Client-side room creation enabled in your [video settings in the Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/video/configure).

[image: Click the button at the bottom of the video settings page to enable client side room creation.]